# Migrating Bootcamp to new SSD

Tags: macos, bootcamp, ssd, migration

I bought a Mac Pro (Late 2013) about a year ago. I recently ran out of space on the built-in 250gb SSD (Windows was the culprit of that), so I bought a 1tb ssd replacement [from eBay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Apple-Samsung-1TB-PCIe-SSD-for-MacBook-Pro-Retina-NEW-Mac-Pro-Late-2013-2014-/151526192552?pt=US_Solid_State_Drives&hash=item2347aa35a8). I just installed it today, and I want to move all of my data over to the new SSD.

I've already got all of the Mac content copying over, as that is really easy, but I also want to put the Bootcamp partition back on the new SSD too. I created a 500GB partition for it, but I don't know how to move the bootable partition over there. I created a DMG from it in Disk Utility before I swapped out the SSDs, and I have that, but Disk Utility won't let me restore it to the new partition I created. It gives me an invalid argument error.

How can I migrate my bootcamp DMG to a partition on my new SSD without having to reinstall it completely?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create an image of the Boot Camp partition of the old SSD using [Winclone](https://twocanoes.com/products/mac/winclone) and restore it to the new SSD.